# Passing boolean useState prop from child to grandparent react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-props

i'm kinda new to react so im sorry for my lack of understanding.
I'm trying to pass a prop from child to grandparent but i'm having some difficulties in achiving that.

The main goal is to pass true/false from child to grandparent in order to hide/show an element - according to button onClick event.
The element appears all the time, but after onClick in Child i want to hide it without refreshing the page.
The element is part of the Grandparent component.

Tne child:

```
Import React, {useState} from 'react';
type ChildProps =  {
   ...
}
   
   export const Child = ({ ... }: ChildProps) => {
    
    const [click, setClick] = useState(true);

     
    const handleClick = () => {
      setClick(!click);
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>on click return false</button>
    );
  };
```

The parent:

```
Import React from 'react';
Import {Child} from './Child';

type ParentProps =  {
   ...
}
   
   export const Parent = ({ ... }: ParentProps) => {
    

    return (
        <Child ... />
    );
  };
```

Grandparent:

```
Import React from 'react';
Import {Parent} from './Parent';

type GrandParentProps =  {
   ...
}

    return (
        {passedProp ? <h1> show this title </h1> : null}
    );
  };
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the state and handle click event in the upper component and pass the onClick function to it's child components.
when button is clicked the state will change in the GrandParent and then you can use the "click" state for conditional rendering of whatever component you like, in the grandparent component

- I would suggest in this case to call the state

```
const [isButtonClicked, setIsButtonClicked] = useState(true);
```

so that is more clear..

```
Import {Parent} from './Parent';
Import React, {useState} from 'react';

type GrandParentProps =  {
   ...
}

export const GrandParent = ({ ... }: GrandParentProps) => {

const [click, setClick] = useState(true);

const handleClick = () => {
  setClick(!click);
}

return (
    <>
      {passedProp ? <h1> show this title </h1> : null}
      <Parent onClick={handleClick}/>

      {click && <SomeComponent />}
    </>
  );
};


Import React from 'react';
Import {Child} from './Child';

type ParentProps =  {
   onClick: () => void;
}
   
   export const Parent = ({ onClick }: ParentProps) => {
    

    return (
       <Child onClick={onClick} />
    );
  };


Import React, {useState} from 'react';

type ChildProps =  {
  onClick: () => void;
}
   
   export const Child = ({ onClick }: ChildProps) => {
    
    return (
        <button onClick={onClick}>on click return false</button>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! :)
Unfortunately that's not what I was looking for - i want to hide the element on the grandparent component, using passedProp 
It goes like this: theres a button on the child component that needs to decide whether the element on the grandparent will show. I tried what you suggested and it makes the element in the child component disappear

Comment: Thank you! ok i understood you wanted to hide the button. so i edited my answer. 
removed the isShown prop and now you just use the click state in the grandparent to hide or show whatever component you want ("SomeComponent" in the example)

Comment: Happy it helped you:) would be lovely and help me if you could accept the answer by clicking the V sign on the left side